# how to solve parser error in my application?

Tags: java, android, saxparser

I parsed my xml file successfully, but now I am getting null value. so what mistake I make in my coding I don't know. I want to display my string value in my screen. Now I am trying to display that string value in text view format, but I am getting null value......

my xml file:

```
<Mobiles>
<Mobile>
<Phone>Nokia 1108</Phone>
<Network>GSM 900/1800 MHz</Network>
<Size>106x46x20 mm</Size>
<Ringtones>mono</Ringtones>
<SMS>yes</SMS>
<MMS>no</MMS>
<Email>no</Email>
<InstantMessaging >no</InstantMessaging>
</Mobile>

<Mobile>
<Phone>Nokia 1109</Phone>
<Network>GSM 900/1800 MHz</Network>
<Size>106x46x20 mm</Size>
<Ringtones>mono</Ringtones>
<SMS>yes</SMS>
<MMS>no</MMS>
<Email>no</Email>
<InstantMessaging >no</InstantMessaging>
</Mobile>

<Mobile>
<Phone>Nokia 1110</Phone>
<Network>GSM 900/1800 MHz</Network>
<Size>106x46x20 mm</Size>
<Ringtones>mono</Ringtones>
<SMS>yes</SMS>
<MMS>no</MMS>
<Email>no</Email>
<InstantMessaging >no</InstantMessaging>
</Mobile>

<Mobile>
<Phone>Nokia 1111</Phone>
<Network>GSM 900/1800 MHz</Network>
<Size>106x46x20 mm</Size>
<Ringtones>mono</Ringtones>
<SMS>yes</SMS>
<MMS>no</MMS>
<Email>no</Email>
<InstantMessaging >no</InstantMessaging>
</Mobile>
</Mobiles>
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you have true in endElement method?

```
 if (localName.equals("Mobiles")) {
                this.in_Mobiles = true;
```

this could leads to always override mobiles and not setting correct field.

Comment: sorry its my mistake now I changed to false now also i am getting null output.

Comment: but Jens is true, since you are always in_Mobiles, you will never set any other field. If you want to, do NOT use else if statement, just series of if statements.

Comment: anyway, you will get only last mobiles data since you will everytime overwrite data in myParsedExampleDataSet

Comment: see my screen shot its my present output. i am confused for this concept sodik.

Answer (score 1):

Just briefly glancing at your code I'd say that the issue is the state transitions on your `in_Mobiles` variable. It will always be `true` from the start of the document to the end.

In your `characters(char[], int, int)` method, the very first conditional branch will thus consume all characters:

```
if (this.in_Mobiles) {
    myParsedExampleDataSet.setMobiles(new String(ch, start, length));
```

The same behavior repeats in the use of `in_Mobile`, which if you fix the first one, will be the next culprit.

**Edit:**
Well, overall your parser implementation is kind of wonky. Try something like this instead:

First off, your ParsedExampleDataSet is a bit off.

Turn it into a List of Mobile objects instead, like this:

```
public class ParsedExampleDataSet extends ArrayList<Mobile>{
}
```

Next, make a bean class named Mobile, like this:

```
class Mobile {
    private String Phone;
    private String Network;
    private String Size;
    private String Ringtones;
    private boolean SMS;
    private boolean MMS;
    private boolean Email;
    private boolean InstantMessaging;
    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }
    public String getNetwork() {
        return Network;
    }
    public void setNetwork(String network) {
        Network = network;
    }
    public String getSize() {
        return Size;
    }
    public void setSize(String size) {
        Size = size;
    }
    public String getRingtones() {
        return Ringtones;
    }
    public void setRingtones(String ringtones) {
        Ringtones = ringtones;
    }
    public boolean isSMS() {
        return SMS;
    }
    public void setSMS(boolean sMS) {
        SMS = sMS;
    }
    public boolean isMMS() {
        return MMS;
    }
    public void setMMS(boolean mMS) {
        MMS = mMS;
    }
    public boolean isEmail() {
        return Email;
    }
    public void setEmail(boolean email) {
        Email = email;
    }
    public boolean isInstantMessaging() {
        return InstantMessaging;
    }
    public void setInstantMessaging(boolean instantMessaging) {
        InstantMessaging = instantMessaging;
    }
}
```

Finally, your DefaultHandler subclass needs to be reworked. Something like this ought to work.

```
class ExampleHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private ParsedExampleDataSet Mobiles;
    private Mobile CurrentMobile;
    private StringBuilder Characters;
    public ParsedExampleDataSet getParsedExampleDataSet() {
        return Mobiles;
    }
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        Mobiles = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
    }
    public void startElement(String namespaceUri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)
            throws SAXException {
        String name = localName.equals("") ? qName : localName;
        if ("Mobile".equals(name)) {
            CurrentMobile = new Mobile();
        }
        // Empty accumulated characters
        Characters = null;
    }
    public void characters(char[] ch, int offset, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (Characters == null) {
            Characters = new StringBuilder(length);
        }
        Characters.append(ch, offset, length);
    }
    public void endElement(String namespaceUri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        String name = localName.equals("") ? qName : localName;
        if ("Mobile".equals(name)) {
            Mobiles.add(CurrentMobile);
            CurrentMobile = null;
        } else if (CurrentMobile != null && Characters != null){
            String value = Characters.toString();
            if ("Phone".equals(name)) {
                CurrentMobile.setPhone(value);
            } else if ("Network".equals(name)) {
                CurrentMobile.setNetwork(value);
            } else if ("Size".equals(name)) {
                CurrentMobile.setSize(value);
            } else if ("Ringtones".equals(name)) {
                CurrentMobile.setRingtones(value);
            } else {
                boolean yes = "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(value.trim());
                if ("SMS".equals(name)) {
                    CurrentMobile.setSMS(yes);
                } else if ("MMS".equals(name)) {
                    CurrentMobile.setMMS(yes);
                } else if ("Email".equals(name)) {
                    CurrentMobile.setEmail(yes);
                } else if ("InstantMessaging".equals(name)) {
                    CurrentMobile.setInstantMessaging(yes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, just running it like this should produce a result:

```
SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
ExampleHandler handler = new ExampleHandler();
InputSource is = new InputSource(/* your XML goes here as an inputstream or reader*/);
parser.parse(is, handler);
ParsedExampleDataSet mobiles = handler.getParsedExampleDataSet();
for (Mobile mobile : mobiles) {
    System.out.println(mobile.getPhone());
}
```

Comment: yup, overall that parser is a bit off. try the included simple example. On the whole, maybe you should use some sort of xml-to-bean library, such as [pulloid](http://code.google.com/p/pulloid/)

Comment: jens now I followed your instructions, now my output show Error: null What's the problem now? see this link full coding: 1. http://paste.org/43227 2. http://paste.org/43228 3. http://paste.org/43229

Comment: Hm, your ParsedExampleDataSet is still full of stuff that shouldn't be there (like all the fields that *should* be in Mobile) & a toString() that makes no sense. You should consider printing the entire error when you catch an exception, i.e. send it to android.util.Log.e(String, String, Exception).